# converting text line breaks in database when they are echo'd out

Tags: php, html, database, textarea, bbcode

I am using ckEditor as a BBCode editor and having to do a bit of deeper work than just installing some plugins.

When saving to the database, in the field i will have e.g.

```
1
2
3
```

Yet when it is echo'd out it is

```
123
```

I need help converting those line breaks in the database, and either putting each line into a

tag or created something out of the line breaks.

I am using this function to convert other BBCodes into html just cant figure out this.

```
function basicbbcode($text) {
    $text = str_replace("[b]", "<b>", "$text");
    $text = str_replace("[/b]", "</b>", "$text");
    return $text;
}
```

The other option i see is to convert the line breaks to 
 etc when inputting to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Let the PHP engine do the work for you with new lines, as it will detect what newline characters to replace automatically.

```
$text = nl2br($text);
```

All done.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the line breaks which are going to be \n, \r or \n\r:

```
$text = str_replace("\n", "<br/>", "$text");
$text = str_replace("\r", "<br/>", "$text");
```

Comment: Simple as that. Im sure there is more that i can check for but this suits me perfectly for now :) Thanks, shall mark as correct answer when i can.

Comment: just use nl2br() ... very old PHP function

Comment: oh, okay ill look into nl2br()

Comment: $text = nl2br($text);

Comment: always a simple answer to a complicated question. Great function! thanks guys.

Comment: Nice! I have not used nl2br() before but will start now! Is there an equivalent if I want </p><p> instead of <br/> ?

Comment: @JesseClark Stuck with string replacements on that one. :-)